# Dependent select boxes JS and JQuery - last box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, box

I have found the below code for some dependent select boxes, but for some reason I am not able to add a fourth select box - I can display it via html but it stays empty, also when field9 is filled in.
Do you see any reason for it?

There should be four select boxes (field6, field8, field9 and field1).
Field 8 should be populating based on the value chosen in field6, field9 based on field8 and field1 based on field9. 
The code is working up until field9. I have then copied the code and adjusted it with the correct references, created field1. But that field is not populated and the drop down  shows as empty.

I am thinking that maybe this query is for three boxes maximum? Is there any way to make the last box work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
       <!-- ****************For State Loads Starts***************************-->
       $("#field6").change(function (e){
       var state = 
       {
       '0': ['Not Available'],
       '':['Select Country'],
       'Z1':['AU','CH'],

       }    
       var value = this.value;
       // Access the object like city['CT'] .. That gives the Array
       state[value] !== undefined ? state[value] : '0';                                 
       var stateOptions = state[value];         
       var $field8 = $('#field8'),
       $field9 = $('#field9');  
        $field1 = $('#field1'); 
        $field1.html('');

       $field8.html(''); // clear the existing options  
       $field9.html(''); // clear the existing options                
       $.each(stateOptions, function (i, o) {
       $('<option>' + o + '</option>').appendTo('#field8');
       });// ------------>each end tag          
       });//----------------->on-change end tag
       <!-- ****************For State Loads Ended***************************-->
       <!-- ****************For type Loads Starts***************************-->
       $("#field8").change(function (e){     
       var type = 
       {
       '0': ['Not Available'],
       'AU' : ['TEST'],
       'CH' : ['TEST1'],

       }
       var value = this.value;
       type[value] !== undefined ? type[value] : '0';
       var typeOptions = type[value];
       var $field9 = $('#field9');              
       $field9.html(''); // clear the existing options 
       $.each(typeOptions, function (j, k) {
       $('<option>' + k + '</option>').appendTo('#field9');
       });// ------------>each end tag
       });//----------------->on-change end tag
       <!-- ****************For type Loads Ended***************************-->
       <!-- ****************For type2 Loads Starts***************************-->
       $("#field9").change(function (e){     
       var type2 = 
       {
       '0' : ['Not Available'],
       'TEST' : ['this should appear in the fourth box'],
       'TEST1' : ['this should appear in the fourth box']


       }
       var value = this.value;
       type2[value] !== undefined ? type2[value] : '0';
       var type2Options = type2[value];
       var $field1 = $('#field1');              
       $field1.html(''); // clear the existing options 
       $.each(type2Options, function (j, k) {
       $('<option>' + k + '</option>').appendTo('#field1');
       });// ------------>each end tag
       });//----------------->on-change end tag
       <!-- ****************For type2 Loads Ended***************************-->
       }); //-------------------->ready end tag
       </script>


       <div id="formElement6" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
       <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
       <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 0%" >
       <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" class="custom-select">
       <label for="Country"><b>SELECT</b></label>
       <select id="field6" name="Country" style="width: 10%">
       <option value="" selected="selected" >Select</option>
       <option value="Z1" >FIRST</option>

       </select>
       </p>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div id="formElement7" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px" >
       <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
       <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
       <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
       <input id="field7" type="hidden" name="DataSource" value=""  />
       </p>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div id="formElement8" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
       <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
       <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 0%" >
       <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" class="custom-select">
       <label for="state" style="font-family=PT Sans" ><b>Country</b></label>
       <select id="field8" name="state" style="width: 15%">

       </select>
       </p>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div id="formElement9" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
       <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
       <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 0%" >
       <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" class="custom-select">
       <label for="type"><b> Type</b></label>
       <select id="field9" name="type" style="width: 15%" >


       </select>
       </p>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>

       <div id="formElement10" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
       <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
       <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 0%" >
       <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" class="custom-select">
       <label for="type2"><b>Type2 </b></label>
       <select id="field1" name="type2" style="width: 40%" >

       </select>
       </p>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#field8").change(function (e){     
       var type = 
       {
       '0': ['Not Available'],
       'AU' : ['TEST'],
       'CH' : ['TEST1'],

       }
```

field9 has an option so function change() not working .
you can set a default option for select boxes .
example :

```
{
 'AU' : ['default','TEST'],
 'CH' : ['default','TEST1'],
}
```